# Convert PDF to PCL using Ghostscript 9.15

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, printer-control-language

Requirement is to convert PDF to PCL with a macro embedded (currently testing this on Windows, however I will need to use this runtime in the application and print it from UNIX). The macro will be used later in another document to embed this cropped image and printed on one single page. I will be using PCL escape codes to call the MacroNumber and then the image will be printed. (You can consider this as a logo image.)

I am able to convert the PDF with whitespace to just the PDF without any whitespace by using CropBox.

```
"c:\progra~1\gs\gs9.15\bin\gswin64.exe" -o _sourcePDFcropped.pdf \
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -c "[/CropBox [1 140 320 650] /PAGES pdfmark" \
    -f _sourcePDF.pdf
```

However, when I convert this `_sourcePDFcropped.pdf` to PCL, this still adding whitespace.

```
"c:\progra~1\gs\gs9.15\bin\gswin64c.exe" -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE \
   -sDEVICE=pxlcolor -g100x200 -sOutputFile=_sourceFedGroundCroppedTest.pcl \
   -f _sourceFedGroundCropped.pdf
```

I tried using [MKPCL](http://spectracolorservices.com/)  and it does the job. Because it doesn't have much support, I am trying to use Ghostscript.

```
MKPCL.EXE -c4 -t -m 100 -p Image.jpg Image.MAC
```

I also tried ImageMagick which internally uses Ghostscript. So I am guessing, if I use the right switches in GS, I should be able to achieve my goal.

Input PDF File: [Click Here](http://docdroid.net/ut2s)

P.S: I have seen other PDF to PCL queries on Stackoverflow, others are more of straight forward PDF to PCL. Mine is to crop the PDF and output should be PCL.

Question continued: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129654/convert-pdf-to-pcl-using-ghostscript-9-15-with-macro-embedded-into-pcl)

Comment: If this isn't possible, please let me know if we can have a transparent background of the PCL output (instead of white background).

Thanks

Comment: If you do not provide a (link to a) sample input PDF, your chances that you'll get a useful answer are lower... Only the input PDF allows to analyze if the CropBox does indeed mask white space around the PDF's page...

Comment: I have added the original input PDF (http://docdroid.net/ut2s)

Comment: I thought I haven't got complete answer :) (w.r.t to macro posted in the question)

Comment: Your question sounded like you knew very well how to handle the macro aspect of it, and that the major problem was the white margins....

Comment: Somehow after embedding macro# for the output using -sDevice=pxlcolor - the macro is not working the same way as expected. If you look at the files mentioned in (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29127411/652184) you will understand it. Thanks. :)

Comment: Upon reseraching more, I found this reg PCLXL: (http://goo.gl/evRAzU)

The PCL6 language is NOT an enhanced form of the PCL5 language - it is totally different.

If you are using a PCL6 driver, you will be creating a PCL6 (PCL XL) print stream.
If you look inside your file, you should see an appropriate
@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = PCLXL
statement which would confirm that you are generating PCL6.

Such a print stream CANNOT be manipulated and used as a macro within a PCL5 environment.

_____

so I think I will need a PCL5 cropped output, so that I can add macro to the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I processed the sample input PDF with the following command line, using a self-compiled Ghostscript v9.16 (unreleased, from current GhostPDL GIT sources):

```
gs -o -                                          \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite                             \
   -c "[/CropBox [1 140 320 650] /PAGES pdfmark" \
   -f source.pdf                                 \
                                                 \
| gs -o tst.pcl                                  \
    -sDEVICE=pxlcolor                            \
    -dUseCropBox                                 \
    -f -
```

<sub>(As you may well have noticed, I'm connecting 2 different Ghostscript commands through a pipe in order to save writing a temporary PDF file to disk.)</sub>

If you want to do the same on Windows, the command line in a `cmd.exe`/DOS box would be:

```
gswin64c.exe -o -                                ^
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite                             ^
   -c "[/CropBox [1 140 320 650] /PAGES pdfmark" ^
   -f source.pdf                                 ^
                                                 ^
| gswin64c.exe -o tst.pcl                        ^
    -sDEVICE=pxlcolor                            ^
    -dUseCropBox                                 ^
    -f -
```

Then I opened it with the self-compiled PCL viewer (also from GhostPDL sources), `pcl6`:

```
pcl6 tst.pcl
```

This is a screenshot showing the `pcl6` window:

[image: pcl6-screenshot]

As KenS also pointed out: it is important to use `-dUseCropBox` when processing the cropped PDF intermediate data!

Comment: You aren't avoiding writing a temporary file to disk, pdfwrite always writes multiple temporary files. All you are doing is preventing writing the intermediate PDF file. I *strongly* advise against piping the output of pdfwrite anywhere, that's not a supported usage, and it definitely will not work if you linearize the PDF file.

Comment: Well, I didnt create a linearize PDF, and I meant to avoid explicit storage andere-reading of an intermediate PDF file. I understand your thought though. ;-)

Comment: My concern is that its not a design goal for pdfwrite, at some point I may change the behaviour so that it won't work at all, and then people will complain if the pipes they've been using stop working.....

Answer (score 1):

Adding a CropBox doesn't really do much, it leaves the PDF exactly the same, but adds a CropBox entry for the page. GS will usually use the MediaBox, not the CropBox, so adding a CropBox to a PDF has no effect.

You could try adding `-dUseCropBox`. If the white space you think is being *added* is in fact present in the original PDF, but masked by the CropBox, then using `-dUseCropBox` will have GS use the CropBox when rendering the PDF.